# Empty custom class of UIButton change its look

Tags: ios, uibutton, xib

I have added 2 UIButtons to view in xib file. I have set custom class of the first button to AButtonTest. Implementation of this class is empty:

```
@implementation AButtonTest

@end
```

I run ios 6 simulator:

[image]

As you can see button on the left looks different. Why ?

Comment: custom type show in with out border on iOS

Comment: first Button is **custom type** where second button is **System type** button., have you change type for first button ?

Comment: @Virussmca I didn't change type of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subclass `UIButton`, the default button type is `UIButtonTypeCustom` not `UIButtonTypeSystem`. Apparently your first button is custom and your second one is system. If you want your first one to be system. You should `alloc` and `init` it.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType%3a):

> If you subclass UIButton, buttonWithType: does not return an instance of
>   your subclass. If you want to create an instance of a specific
>   subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set custom property of UIButton in the .xib.